# Why the queue results are different only by changed mechanism?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a **host** that has a method which pops up a **MessageBox**

the client just activate the function.

it is working but something is weird :

```
  ChannelFactory<IMessagingService> channel = new ChannelFactory<IMessagingService>("NetTcpBinding_IMessagingService");

                 IMessagingService proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
                 proxy.Hello("Royi");
```

if i click on the button in the client many times  i see several meesage box ( without closing the last one !!!!!)

[image]

but if i change the client code to :  ( just by the **using** mechanism)

```
 ChannelFactory<IMessagingService> channel = null;

            using (channel= new ChannelFactory<IMessagingService>("NetTcpBinding_IMessagingService"))
             {
                 IMessagingService proxy = channel.CreateChannel();
                 proxy.Hello("Royi");
             }
```

and if i try to press many times on the client button - **it WONT ALLOW ME !!**

[image]

this is the code at the host which generates the popup

```
   [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class MessagingService : IMessagingService
    {

        public void Hello(string message)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }


    }
```

i want to understand **why**

thank you.

Comment: I would rather see code than those fancy pictures.

Comment: i wrote the code.... ( also )

Comment: So where's the callback (Pop) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First gues (without knowing what the channelfactory does):
Using will call the dispose method after proxy.Hello. The first example uses multiple ChannelFactories next to eachother (till the GC destroys them), while the 2nd always destroyes the ChannelFactory after you print Hello.

Comment: event if i destroy it - when i press again it recreates it ... no ?

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete code but this looks like  a Dual binding. You've got to keep the channel open on that one.

Comment: so the problem is that the channel is being destroyed without the ability to recreate himself ?

Comment: I think destroying the channel means it shouldn't work, which makes the 1st one a mistery. Could be working thanks to the startup delay.

Comment: You could test this theory with a Sleep(2000) inside the using.